# How to stop regex conflicting with : in bootstrapValidate plugin

Tags: javascript, regex, bootstrap-4

I am using the following regex with [bootstrapValidate plugin](https://github.com/PascaleBeier/bootstrap-validate) to validate a field.

```
bootstrapValidate('#input', 'regex:/^(my:track:[a-zA-Z0-9]{22}$)/:Invalid input')
```

The docs state to use this expression:

```
bootstrapValidate('#input', 'regex:^[a-z]+$:Please fulfill my regex')
```

The issue is I am using `:` inside the regex match and conflicts with the separator options.

How can I stop the `:` regex conflicting? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3processing.com/index.php?subMenuLoad=javascript/RegExp/RegExpUsing.php

This site says colon is a control character which must be escaped with a backslash (quoted below).

> If you want to include any of these characters literally in a regular
>   expression, you must precede them with the backslash character \
>   (escape character).

```
var pattern1 = /\\/;  \\ match backslash character
var pattern2 = /\[/;  \\ match starting square brackets
var pattern3 = /\:/;  \\ match colon character
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the following: `bootstrapValidate('#input', 'regex:my\:track\:[a-zA-Z0-9]{22}$:Invalid input')` and `bootstrapValidate('#input', 'regex:my/\:/track/\:/[a-zA-Z0-9]{22}$:Invalid input')` but still doesn't validate.

Comment: I was looking at bootstrap's code out of curiosity.  If you look at what field it's expecting, it's regexp, not regex.  Perhaps it should be 'regexp:my\: ...' instead?

Comment: Bootstrap code for regex validator:  https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/blob/master/src/js/validator/regexp.js

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this is for [bootstrap-validate js](https://bootstrap-validate.js.org/rules.html) plugin. `regex` is the correct use here.